# Redirecionar paginas usando atributos if, else if e else o que está errado?

Tags: php, if, else

meu codigo php

```
<?php

include "conectar.php";


//comando para iserir dados direto do formul?rio para o banco de dados

$nome=$_POST["nome"];
$cpf=$_POST["cpf"];
$identidade=$_POST["identidade"];
$telefone=$_POST["telefone"];
$celular=$_POST["celular"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$cep=$_POST["cep"];
$endereco=$_POST["endereco"];
$complemento=$_POST["complemento"];
$bairro=$_POST["bairro"];
$cidade=$_POST["cidade"];
$uf=$_POST["uf"];
$sexo=$_POST["sexo"];
$idade=$_POST["identidade"];
$peso=$_POST["peso"];
$individual=$_POST["individual"];
$tresvidas=$_POST["tresvidas"];
$cincovidas=$_POST["cincovidas"];


$sql="INSERT INTO cadsolidario VALUES ('$nome', '$cpf', '$identidade', '$telefone', '$celular', '$email', '$cep', '$endereco', '$complemento', '$bairro', '$cidade', '$uf', '$sexo', '$idade', '$peso', '$individual', '$tresvidas', '$cincovidas')";
$RES=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$num=mysqli_affected_rows($con);

if($num = "tresvidas"){
include('busca.php');

}else if($num = "cincovidas"){
    include('index.php');

}else{
     include('consulta-consultas.php');
}

?>
```

observaçao: esta inserindo os dados corretamente.
Mas não está redirecionando o que devo fazer? Obrigado!

Comment: Olá Flavio, faltou o código.

Comment: Para compara valores usa-se dois sinais de iguais `==` e não um (que é atribuição)

Comment: ok vou auterar e digo se houve mudanças, obrigado! -rray

Comment: Tenho a impressão que sempre vai cair no `else`, `$num` recebe um número mas você compara com uma string...

Comment: Éexatamente o que está acontecendo, devo colocar $res? confesso que fiquei totalmente perdido! Rs.

Comment: @FlavioCordas De onde vem as palavras "tresvidas" e "cincovidas"? Da base de dados?

Comment: Eu não sei o que você está comparando nem o pq, precisa explicar esses detalhes editando a pergunta.

Comment: opa desculpe a demora! eu quero que a partir dos dados digitados no formulario, onde $tresvidas=$_POST['tresvidas']; for escolhido me leve para pagina busca php! Entende?

Comment: `tresvidas` é um radio button ou select?

Answer (score 1):

O `mysqli_affected_rows()` devolve o **NÚMERO** de rows afetadas, no entanto, você está a comparar com uma string.

Notei também que você está a usar `=` nos seus `if`. O que tem de errado é que `=` é usado em comparações em `PHP` enquanto `==` é usado para ver se um valor é exatamente igual ao outro.

Comment: Verdade, também tem isto, aproveita e adiciona a resposta o problema que o rray falou https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/255954/redirecionar-paginas-usando-atributos-if-else-if-e-else-o-que-est%c3%a1-errado#comment525182_255954

Comment: Boa noite, eu quero selecionar no formulário ou tresvidas ou cincovidas e a partir daí de acordo com a seleção me enviar para as respectivas paginas. Estou realmente precisando dessa ajuda, desculpem a demora!

Comment: Amigos já resolvi!

Comment: if($tresvidas == "tresvidas"){
include('tresvidas.php');

}else if($cincovidas == "cincovidas"){
    include('dependentes.php');
 
}else{
  include('index.php');
}


mysqli_close($con);